# How do I set up a keyboard shortcut to close the project properties page in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Visual Studio 2015.  I set up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut to close windows in the editor.  When I have the properties page for a project open; however, if I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, nothing happens.

How do I set up a keyboard shortcut to close the project properties page?

Answer (score 0):

There are two commands: **Window.CloseDocumentWindow** (<kbd>Ctrl+F4</kbd> by default) and **Window.CloseToolWindow** (<kbd>Shift+Esc</kbd> by default).

Comment: What should I use for the value of the "Use new shortcut in" selection?

Comment: @user2023861 Global.

Comment: That's not working for me.  I don't think there's another shortcut interferring with it.  I removed the Window.CloseDocumentWindow shortcut I already had to be sure of this.